# Chrome Developer Tools - How to find the source where variables shown in the console are defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the console of Chrome Developer Tools we are able to view all the variables and functions that are in scope for a given page, like shown in this screenshot which shows a function called "buildIssInitObject" defined on our favorite shopping site http://grab.by/RbjQ.

But what is not shown is where this function or variable is defined. Usually a page loads many source files, so how to see in which of these a given function or variable displayed in the console has been defined?

Comment: on the right corner you may see the file name and line umber

Comment: no, I don't see that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find all references, including the declaration, by searching in the Sources tab using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Window) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Mac). Click on the result to open the file.

**Note:** The file that the function definition exists in is not necessarily the original file created during development. In this case, the code is bundled from many different sources.

[image: Search]

Alternatively, use the overflow menu to open the Search bar if the shortcut has been hijacked by another application, such as Spectacle:

[image: Overflow menu for Search all files]

Comment: I am on a Mac and I went to the Source tab and hit Cmd+Shift+F but nothing seems to happen, is there another way to open search besides this shortcut? Cmd+F seems to work but that is only for a file which is already open.

Comment: @AbuMariam The shortcut is correct, but if you have any app that hijacks your shortcuts, such as Spectacle, it won't work. You can use the right overflow menu in DevTools to bring it up manually. See updated answer.

Comment: on a Mac, I think its Cmd+Option+F. But your answer helped, thanks much!!

Comment: @AbuMariam Ah yes, copy and pasted that wrong. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For functions, Chrome also lets you jump directly to the function definition.

You can either do this by hovering over the variable and clicking the link.

[image]

Or you can right-click on the variable and select "Show Function Definition".

[image]